# Can't block syndication.twitter.com in pfSense

Tags: networking, google-chrome, pfsense

I noticed, that address https://syndication.twitter.com/ is often hangs in Chrome, and added it into pfSense Firewall block list.

Unfortunately, I still can open this page (receiving 404 error).

How to fix?

I noticed, that `syndication.twitter.com` has different IP addresses on PING. Is this a reason of unablility to block?

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed, that syndication.twitter.com has different IP addresses on PING. Is this a reason of unablility to block?

High availability websites have more than one server with each their own instance. Therefore, they have more than one IP address to reach the website.

The tricky party is obtaining a list of these IP addresses, because different DNS servers can be configured to return different IP addresses. Therefore just listing the IP addresses of one DNS server does not usually suffice; listing those of a few DNS servers is a safer bet, but you might still miss one.

Go to [Dig web interface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?showcommand=on&colorize=on&ns=all) and enter `syndication.twitter.com` in the box at the left, then **dig** it.

Note that I have preselected some options for you, one of which selects most common DNS servers. If you are handy with scripting or don't mind to search and ask some extra questions, you might be able to compile your own list of DNS servers and rewrite the output to get just the IP addresses.

It's worth noting that these IPs usually reside in the same subnetwork; so, once you identify some IPs you might opt to block the entire subnetwork containing them. A reverse DNS lookup is your friend.

**Output:**

```
syndication.twitter.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @8.8.4.4
syndication.twitter.com. 19 IN  A   199.59.148.85
syndication.twitter.com. 19 IN  A   199.59.150.46
syndication.twitter.com@165.87.13.129 (AT&T (US)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @165.87.13.129
syndication.twitter.com. 16 IN  A   199.16.156.21
syndication.twitter.com. 16 IN  A   199.16.156.52
syndication.twitter.com@8.8.8.8 (Google):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @8.8.8.8
syndication.twitter.com. 19 IN  A   199.59.148.85
syndication.twitter.com. 19 IN  A   199.59.150.46
syndication.twitter.com@168.95.1.1 (HiNet (TW)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @168.95.1.1
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.136
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.200
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.72
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.8
syndication.twitter.com@208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @208.67.222.222
syndication.twitter.com. 5  IN  A   199.16.156.241
syndication.twitter.com. 5  IN  A   199.16.157.105
syndication.twitter.com@195.129.12.122 (UUNET (CH)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @195.129.12.122
syndication.twitter.com. 8  IN  A   104.244.42.8
syndication.twitter.com. 8  IN  A   104.244.42.136
syndication.twitter.com. 8  IN  A   104.244.42.72
syndication.twitter.com. 8  IN  A   104.244.42.200
syndication.twitter.com@192.76.144.66 (UUNET (DE)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @192.76.144.66
syndication.twitter.com. 30 IN  A   104.244.42.200
syndication.twitter.com. 30 IN  A   104.244.42.136
syndication.twitter.com. 30 IN  A   104.244.42.72
syndication.twitter.com. 30 IN  A   104.244.42.8
syndication.twitter.com@158.43.240.3 (UUNET (UK)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @158.43.240.3
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.8
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.200
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.136
syndication.twitter.com. 13 IN  A   104.244.42.72
syndication.twitter.com@198.6.100.25 (UUNET (US)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @198.6.100.25
syndication.twitter.com. 16 IN  A   199.59.150.46
syndication.twitter.com. 16 IN  A   199.59.148.85
syndication.twitter.com@64.6.64.6 (Verisign (US)):
dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats syndication.twitter.com. @64.6.64.6
syndication.twitter.com. 29 IN  A   199.16.156.120
syndication.twitter.com. 29 IN  A   199.16.157.105
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding all ip of syndication.twitter.com and block all of them you can use dns forwarder

Goto Services > DNS Forwarder add Host Override Options and fill the form

Host: syndication
Domain:twitter.com
IP Address: any ip (like 192.168.1.1) or unknown ip
Description: xyz
and Click on save
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kryfP.png)
Wait 5 min and try to access again it will defenately not accessable

Regards
Kishor